# Como se dice "The beautiful Spain" en Español?

Tags: traducción

Quisiera saber como podría decirse “We are in the beautiful Spain” en Español?
Es possible decir “Estamos en España la linda”?

Comment: Me escucha mejor así, estamos en la España, es muy linda. In english it'd be, we are in Spain it's very beautiful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es posible decirlo, otras posibles traducciones serían: "Estamos en la bella España", "Estamos en la linda España" o "Estamos en la bonita España".

Comment: ¿Cual es más corecto o más común?

Comment: Todas son correctas, de las tres mencionadas y la primera mencionada por vos (o vosotros) diría que "Estamos en España la linda" es menos común pues considero que es un estilo utilizado más en literatura.

Comment: Yo añadiría "Estamos en la hermosa España". En España creo que usaríamos, en este contexto, *bella* o *hermosa*; *linda* nos sonaría latinoamericano y *bonita* da idea de algo más pequeño.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción que me parece un buen término medio entre formal y coloquial es "Estamos en la **preciosa** España". En España al menos se utiliza mucho.